# Cannot use serializer when ManyToManyField is empty

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am utilizing [`PrimaryKeyRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) to retrieve and write M2M data.

My **models.py**:

```
class Task(MP_Node):
    ...
    linked_messages = models.ManyToManyField('workdesk.Message', blank=True, related_name='supported_tasks')
```

(`MP_Node` is an abstraction of models.Model from `django-treebeard`).

My **serializers.py**:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    linked_messages = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, required=False, allow_null=True, queryset=Message.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = [..., 'linked_messages']
```

My **api.py**:

```
class TaskViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer

def create(self, request):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        print(serializer.data)
```

With other fields, if the field is set to `null=True` in the models, or `required=False` on the serializer, I don't need to include them in the data to instantiate the serializer. However, these fields do not seem to work this way, instead returning `KeyError: 'linked_messages'` when `serializer.data` is called.

As a workaround I tried adding setting `allow_null`, as indicated by the docs, and then manually feed it a null value:

```
request.data['linked_messages'] = None
```

but this returns as 404:

```
"linked_messages":["This field may not be null."]
```

If I set it to a blank string:

```
"resources":["Expected a list of items but got type \"str\"."]
```

If I set it to an empty list, `serializer.data` again gives me an error:

```
`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`
```

It seems to have me any way I turn. What am I not understanding about this field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **`default`** argument -

```py
linked_messages = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
    many=True,
    queryset=Message.objects.all(),
    default=[]
)

# print(serializer.data)
# {'linked_messages': []}
```